# Passing command line argument in AutoIt to PuTTY

Tags: putty, autoit

I am trying to implement launching PuTTY with AutoIt.

I have a PuTTY configuration session, I named it **'testcom11'**. It saves a PuTTY session with settings for **com11**, **baudrate** and so on.

I implemented in AutoIt a line as following:

```
Run ("putty -load testcom11")
```

It works fine. I was able to launch PuTTY with my session and PuTTY windows pops up and I was able to type an 'AT' command to the PuTTY window.

Now I want, instead of hard coding one session name, to pass a session name from the command line like this:

```
myAutoItprogram.exe testcom11
```

I put this line in AutoIt:

```
$cmp = $CmdLine[1]
```

I can see it passed correctly when I print (display it with, let's say, MsgBox) `$cmp`, it shows `testcom11`.

In the next line I have:

```
Run ("putty -load $cmp")
```

However, AutoIt launches PuTTY only with the window asking me to load a session. So clearly it didn't read the `-load $cmp` option.

As you can see I am novice to AutoIt, so maybe you can see if it is something with how it handles `$cmp` in Run Window or something else.

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax is bad.

AutoIt is maybe similar to PHP, but...

```
$a = "x"
$b = "$ay"
if you print $b you will get this text $ay
```

The correct way would be

```
$b = $a & "y"
```

Now $b will print **xy**.

So in your case its

```
Run("putty -load " & $cmp)
```

instead of

```
Run ("putty -load $cmp")
```

Also about the AutoIt Commandline. There is `$CmdLineRaw` and it will get the whole commandline. In order to get every parameter separated, you can use `$CmdLine[n]` (with `n` being replaced by each parameters index).

Maybe its better to use `$CmdLineRaw`, because you pass only one parameter, and you might avoid a possible problem if that parameter has a space in it.

Comment: Hi Samoth, Milos,  Thank you for answering my question. I tried what you suggested today and it worked very well.  I was able to pass command line parameter as I had hoped for. Putty recognized option and launched session flawlessly.  So again thank you for helping me.

Comment: You're welcome @Zeljo . Don't forget to select my answer. Cheers